# mount http host as local dirctory something like curlftpfs

Tags: ubuntu, http

Is there any way to mount a HTTP host as local directory  .so we can mount ftp host as local directory using curlftpfs.Is there any option for HTTP.Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mount http server as filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/1070851/mount-http-server-as-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount FTP because the protocol offers you commands to run to change directories and list directories/files.

However HTTP is not for listing anything but showing you the contents of things you name by the URL. Even when a file list is shown to you, it's not a real file list but the content of a file generated by the HTTP server. In addition, what you name may be non-existent at all but shown to you by some program. Or it is not in that directory that you think it is in. Or your item to list is not a file but another site.

All in all, if a site allows you to see the file index for a directory, then it can be seen in your browser as if it was mounted. If it denies you to see, then no clever pseudo-mount will be able to show you more than than the list of URL on the page in question, and those URL's can be anything but files, anywhere than you look for.

Comment: what about sshfs

Comment: Based on commands sent through ssh.

Comment: However, some ftp clients allow to list the content of an HTTP folder in an ftp-like fashion. Try, for example, `lftp http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/archive/p8/task/archive/ -e ls`, and the listing is shown... I wonder whether this can be adapted for a FUSE filesystem