# mount http server as filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, http, file-sharing

I am trying to mount HTTP locally.Using SSHFS its working fine.But for Windows systems, or systems without SSH we cant use SSHFS.For example we can mount FTP locally using curlftp.For HTTP we have any commends like curlftp.Any help would appreciable

Answer (score 2):

Go and have a look at WinSCP https://winscp.net its not for mounting but at least you can open a Server on Windows in a Explorer like Looking Window.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use python sufficently, you could give pyfilesystem a try. It can read files over http by the merit of fs.https module. Usually pythoncode runs fine on windows, but YMMV.

http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/httpfs.html

Comment: Your link is not valid anymore :( It went away. And no `httpfs` is listed at https://www.pyfilesystem.org/page/index-of-filesystems/